# DateTime usage confirmation Android

Tags: android, date, jodatime

Am using DateTime from Jodatime to know , the current date is greater or lesser than given date. given date is:

```
12/31/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

my code is:

```
   SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");

              java.util.Date date = null;

              Date date1 = form.parse(mydate);
              int year=date1.getHours();
              int month=date1.getMonth();


              day=date1.getDate();



              int minute=date1.getMinutes();
              int seco=date1.getSeconds();
              int hour=date1.getHours();

              DateTime myBirthDate = new DateTime(year,month, day, hour, minute,seco);
              DateTime now = new DateTime();

myBirthDate.isAfterNow();
```

its returning `false`

and when i pass date: `4/13/2011 12:00:00 AM`

same `false` is returning

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: where you are setting future date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
int year=date1.getHours();
```

Also you can shorten your code like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa");
DateTime myBirthDate = formatter.parseDateTime(mydate);
myBirthDate.isAfterNow();
```